# CSS - transition height on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi,

I want to make a hyperlink that expands from the top down when clicked and closes when clicked again. I also want a fade effect applied to the link text.

I tried something like this :

**HTML**

```
<div id="lime">
         <a href="#">hi</a>
         <p id="red">How are you doing?</p>
         </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#lime
{
background-color:#deff00;
text-align:center;
}
#lime:hover{
height:300px;
transition:height 1s;
}
#lime:hover p{
opacity:1;
transition:opacity 1s;
}
#red {
opacity:0;
color:#ff0000;
}
```

[CSS Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3S8Ep/)

But the effect takes place on hovering over the link. What I'd like is for the link to expand from the top down when clicked.

I also tried this but I don't know anything about javascript.

**HTML**

```
<div><a href="#" id="btn">hi</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
background-color:#deff00;
text-align:center;
}
#expand {
height:300px;
transition:height 1s;
}
#contract {
background-color:#deff00;
transition:height 1s;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){    
$('#expand') function(){
    $('#contract').transition('height 1s');
});
};
```

[Javascript Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7yeG7/)

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Nope. i should use it for javascript ?

Comment: Nope, it's not a must, but I can see that you are already using it. Anyway, are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7yeG7/3/)?

Comment: Yes! but it may be something like, if I click again "hi" it goes from backwards? instead of starting from the beginning?

Comment: Ok, then you are probably looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7yeG7/5/).

Comment: yes! I was trying to make it work for 4 hours and you did it in less than 10 minutes! thank you very much.

Comment: Well, then I will put it as the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create two style class - one will expand your `div` to the desired height, and another will collapse it to the initial position. Code sample follows -

**HTML**

```
<div id="lime"><a href="#" id="btn">hi</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    background-color:#deff00;
    text-align:center;
    height: 20px;
}

#contract {
    background-color:#deff00;
    transition:height 1s;
}

.expand {
    height:300px;
    transition:height 1s;
}

.collapse {
    height: 20px;
    transition:height 1s;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function (e) {    
        if ($("#lime").hasClass("expand")) {
            $("#lime").removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
        }
        else {
            $("#lime").removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7yeG7/6/).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily to this using j Query.

Example shown below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>slideDown demo</title>
<style>
#lime
    {
    background-color:#deff00;
    text-align:center;
    }

.para {
    color:red;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="lime">
             <a href="#" id="click">hi</a>
             <p id="red" class="para">How are you doing?</p>
</div>
<script>
$( "#click" ).click(function() {
$( "#red" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
</script></body>
</html>
```

You can refer this link http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Answer (score 0):

I am totally agree with Sayem Ahmed's answer...

Here some additional answer 
**Option 1.** If you are using jQuery at that time you can use toggle also for achieving this scenario.

Here is

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/3S8Ep/7/)

**Option 2.** You can use pure javascript code for making it done.

Here is

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/3S8Ep/8/)

Hope this will be helpful !!